# Should threads in a Delphi program have the same priorty, when one thread spawns other threads?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

My Delphi program performs a number of tests of sensors, external to the PC. Each test is programmed as a thread. Each test is performed by selecting a Delphi menu item to run the test.  Only one thread is run at a time.

One option, however, is to run all of the tests, automatically, in sequence.  This is done by another thread, which creates, executes, and destroys each of the sensor test threads, one at a time, in sequence.

Should the priority (TThread.priority) of the controller thread  be the same as the threads that it creates, runs, and destroys?

Comment: Why would it not be? It's performing a sequential operation; changing its priority wouldn't accomplish anything.

Comment: In almost all cases, changing thread priorities is a bad idea - doing so invites [priority inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) hangs.

Comment: And the controller thread is mostly waiting for test-thread `FTestThread.Wait();` ... so why bother about the priority ... just do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller thread will be waiting on the test threads, one at a time. The system scheduler knows that the controller thread is waiting. It doesn't make any difference what priority it has when it is blocking. Since the controller thread, for all intents and purposes, spends its entire life blocking, I see no reason to change its priority. Leave it at the default normal priority, the same as all your other threads.